# How to pass additional query parameters in oj.router navigation? Oracle Jet

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-jet

How to pass additional query parameters in oj.router navigation?
This is an Oracle Jet Application

Comment: please share with us what have you tried so far ?

Comment: This question is very vague... Please show us what you're trying to do